# ionic 4 angular when try to run the code i get this error

Tags: ionic4

```
export class HomePage {

    percent = 0;
    radius = 100;
    fullTime: any = '00:01:30';

    timer: any = false;
    progress: any = 0;
    minutes: 1;
    seconds: any = 30;

    startTime() {
        this.timer = false;
        this.percent = 0;
        this.progress = 0;
        const timeSpilt: any = this.fullTime.spilt(':');
        this.minutes = timeSpilt[1];
        this.seconds = timeSpilt[2];
        const totalSeconds: number = Math.floor(this.minutes * 60) + parseInt(this.seconds);
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
            if (this.percent === this.radius) {
                clearInterval(this.timer);
            }
            this.percent = Math.floor((this.progress / totalSeconds) * 100);
            this.progress++;
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

**Error**:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.fullTime.spilt is not a function
    at HomePage.push../src/app/home/home.page.ts.HomePage.startTime (home.page.ts:24)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (HomePage.html:6)
    at handleEvent (core.js:23097)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:24167)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:23894)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:20546)
    at core.js:20993
    at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:993)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17280)
```

Comment: can you tell me what do you get when you do console.log(this.fullTime) before you do the split operation?

Comment: Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a typo in your function method:
**spilt** is indeed no function, try using **split**

```
 this.fullTime.split(':')
```